# How to prevent specific line/s inside a notepad file from being edited?

Tags: windows

I have a file that can be opened thru notepad application.
Basically, this file(which can be opened thru notepad) is created by a software and that software uses the values inside that file to run. You can edit the values inside the file using its software.

I just want specific lines(values) to be restricted from being edited because I am implementing strict values inside that file that no one will be able to edit except me.

Is there any clever way to restrict specific lines inside that file from being edited? 
I tried the basic way - I used the change permission read/write on that file but I can't change ANY values inside the file which is undesirable.

Note: I have very little to no experience about python, c++, or java but any suggestion will give me idea to learn from it.

Edit:

```
Here's an example inside the file:
[Type Data]
Comment=Standard Dispense
[Shared_A]
802=1
807=750
11=0
12=0
.

What I want is restrict the value from row/column "807" which is equal to number 750.

I want this number 750 not to be edited even from the software so that other people will not mess it up. I want to set this value as standard value.

Is there any program that you can write inside that file so that it cannot be edited from the software unless I open that file and edit it?

I work from a production/manufacturing company that uses the software that is used for dispensing.
```

Comment: Use two separate files.

Comment: thanks for reply. :) but what will I do on the second file?

Comment: I am not sure why you need something like this, so I can't make a good suggestion without knowing the exact scenario. But what I suggest is one of the files will contain usual stuff, other file will contain things you do not want to be changed. A program has permission to change file or not, there is no restricted areas in a file.

Comment: Also since this question is not about programming directly, you may want to ask this on https://superuser.com/ instead of here, with explanation of why you need such feature.

Comment: I edited the description of my problem to make it clear. Apologies if I didn't explained it well

Answer (score 0):

A text file is simply a sequence of bytes that represent code units to encode code points in any given character set. Every byte value is a potentially legal character encoding, leaving no values to encode additional semantics (like guard regions).

With that it should be obvious that there is nothing you can do to partially limit editing of a file using a standard text editor. Whatever problem you are trying to solve, this is not a solution. Next time around you might want to ask about the problem you are trying to solve rather than your proposed solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is noted. I added explanation on my problem to make it clear. Apologies for the not clear problem and purpose. This is my first time trying to seek help from this website.

Comment: Unfortunately, you do not appear to understand, how computers work. The attempt to clarify the question did nothing to actually clarify the question.